# Propel reverse engineer mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, propel

Going by the instructions here: http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.5/Existing-Database

I've created a folder and placed a file "build.properties" with the contents:

```
propel.project = test

# The Propel driver to use for generating SQL, etc.
propel.database = mysql

# This must be a PDO DSN
propel.database.url = localhost:dbname=test
propel.database.user = root
propel.database.password = root
```

In the cmd I type    propel-gen reverse

And the error message i get: There was an error building XML from metadata: could not find driver

After hours of searching i feel i've tried every config.  I've enabled the drivers in the php.ini file:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll 
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

I'm using Zend Server

any ideas?

Comment: What's the path on the PC to php_mysql.dll and php_pdo_mysql.dll?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this:

> propel.database.url = localhost:dbname=test

to this

propel.database.url = **mysql:host=localhost;**dbname=test

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Thanks Jordi, saved me a bunch of heartache

Answer (score 0):

**Note** *Entered as answer since comments don't let me format code nicely*

I don't think this is propel related; something is wrong with the PDO driver installation.

Assuming the following generates an exception, can you post the output (edit into question)?

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'root');
?>
```